# use db.update to update all the documents

Tags: mongodb

I want to use mongo shell to update some documents which looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54265f801681140a66ca45de"), "username" : "000000002-xqsh", "name" : "xxxxx", "__v" : 0 }
```

I want to change the dash `-` to underscore `_` in `username` filed. Could I make it by mongo shell?
my mongo shell version as follows:

```
> version()
2.6.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.c.find({username : /-/}, {username : 1}).forEach(function(e) {
    var username = e.username.replace("-", "_");
    db.c.update({_id : e._id}, {$set : {username : username}});
});
```

If you want to replace all "-" in username, use

```
db.c.find({username : /-/}, {username : 1}).forEach(function(e) {
    var username = e.username.replace(/-/g, "_");
    db.c.update({_id : e._id}, {$set : {username : username}});
});
```